# Excel VB Code for Sending Email: Adding email to CC

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up a VB code which can send an email based to specific Emails address given in the column "L" of Sheet 1. The Challenge i am facing is to add ".CC" line. The 'email' addresses for my intended 'CC' list is available on column M of the shame excel sheet "Sheet01"

Can someone suggest appropriate coding for pulling emails to CC line?

Note: Length of CC list (Column M) is not static or is varying.

Thank you

```
Sub CDO_Personalized_Mail_Body()
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim cell As Range
  Dim Flds As Variant

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "Test@gmail.com"  
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "12345@passowrd"  
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
    .Update
End With

For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("L").Cells
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
            Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
            With iMsg
                Set .Configuration = iConf
                .To = cell.Value
                .From = """Test User"" <TestUser@gmail.com>" 
                .CC = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("M").Cells  ' **here i want Insert CC line Email ID** 
                .Subject = "***Important - Email Alert***"
                .TextBody = "Hi " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "This is Auto genrated email " & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                            "Thank You"
                .Send
            End With
            Set iMsg = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

A range has the .Row property that returns the row number of its first row. So for a single cell, cell.Row gives its row.

```
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each cell In sh.UsedRange.Columns("L").Cells
    ' CC cell: same row, column M
    Set cellCC = sh.Cells(cell.Row, "M")
    Debug.Print cell.Row, cellCC.Value
Next cell
```

Note that you should have a Sheet.UsedRange. in there, or `For Each` will loop over the whole 1,048,576 rows of the sheet.

For this kind of task, I prefer not to use `For Each` but a "standard" loop over the rows like the following, IMHO it's better readable.

```
For y = 1 To sh.Columns("L").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Debug.Print y, sh.Cells(y, "L").Value, sh.Cells(y, "M").Value
Next y
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Andre451.. I will test this and let you know